# SSIS- Sharepoint list data transfer issue

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

We are trying to transfer data from oracle database (about 60,0000) records only to a sharepoint list using SSIS. But we are getting following error when records reaches around 19000 .
The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020 and
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

Earlier we thought if could because of Sharepoint list limit so we tried by reducing two of the columns *and then it has went fine.*

So we left with one of the column of Datatype DT_STR and length 400 in oracle beacuse of which issue might be happening, It is mapped to sharepoint custom list field of multiline type.

We also verified if length of field is issue but in oracle DB for all records max length for this column is only 239 so length issue is also ruled out.

Any one who has faced this kind of issue or knows cause of this issue.Kindly let us know..

Thanks and regards,

Vicky

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/c8090eb5-654b-4e6d-a8c2-29fb3cedaa43

Comment: Nopes, We found that issue is because of special characters in source column which Sharepoint list is not accepting through web service call.